# How to send Huawei push notification through Proxy using Java

Tags: java, proxy, huawei-mobile-services

How to send push notification for Huawei devices using Java through proxy server

```
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(this.HcmPushUrl);
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(JSON.toJSONString(map), "UTF-8");
    httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    String rpsContent = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Which is something similar to ProxyManager.setProxy(proxyAddress, proxyPort) of APNS call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please kindly refer to the following code:

```
HuaweiCredential credential = HuaweiCredential.builder()
.setAppId(appId)
.setAppSecret(appSecret)
.setHttpClient()//set your own http client with proxy here
.build();

// Create HuaweiOption
HuaweiOption option = HuaweiOption.builder()
.setCredential(credential)
.setHttpClient()//set your own http client with proxy here
.build();
```

HMS Pushkit Java Severdemo On [Github](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-push-serverdemo-java)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. The above snippet is working fine for me. Also added below code for creating httpclient and passed the same insetHttpClient(), it is just a reference for others.      `code`HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyIp, proxyPort, "http");
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setProxy(proxy).build();